# How to remove CubeJS default Group By clause from query

Tags: node.js, cube.js

**CubeJS** default applies the **Group By** clause when we run any query in it.

For example below is my JSON query for employee Cube:

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    "Employee.date",
    "Employee.state",
    "Employee.id"
  ],
  "timeDimensions": [],
  "filters": []
}
```

When I run above JSON query in CubeJS it will run below SQL:

```sql
SELECT
  `employee`.updatedAt `employee__date`,
  `employee`.state `employee__state`,
  `employee`.EmpId `employee__id`
FROM
  DEMO.Employee AS `employee`
GROUP BY
  1,
  2,
  3
ORDER BY
  1 ASC
LIMIT
  10000
```

For reference below is ***Employee*** Cube that I have :

```
cube(`Employee`, {
  sql: `SELECT * FROM DEMO.Employee `,
  title: `Employee`,

  measures: {
    count: {
      type: `count`
    }
  },
  dimensions: {
    id: {
      sql: `EmpId`,
      type: `string`
    },
    date: {
      sql: `updatedAt`,
      type: `time`
    },
    state: {
      sql: `state`,
      type: `string`
    }
  }
});
```

What will be the JSON query that I need to create if I expect below SQL :

```sql
SELECT
  `employee`.updatedAt `employee__date`,
  `employee`.state `employee__state`,
  `employee`.EmpId `employee__id`
FROM
  DEMO.Employee AS `employee`
WHERE
  `employee`.updatedAt ` BETWEEN '2019-01-01' AND '2019-05-01'
LIMIT
  10000
```

#### OR

Is there any way to remove ***Group By*** clause from the SQL query generated by CubeJS itself.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There's `ungrouped` query property since 0.10.62 for that: https://cube.dev/docs/query-format#query-properties. In your case following query can be used:

```
{
  "dimensions": [
    "Employee.date",
    "Employee.state",
    "Employee.id"
  ],
  "timeDimensions": [],
  "filters": [],
  "ungrouped": true
}
```

Comment: @HarshalNathe No probs!